# how to restrict glob function in python

Tags: python, glob, restriction

I have a folder with several files, and I want to do a simple count inside, for that I am tracking the names of the files. The problem is that before hand I edited several of the files and I have two files that start with the same name and adding a .bak (of backup)

Example of files name in the folder:

1. RF12.st
2. RF85.st
3. RF85.st.bak

(the total number of files is ~2300)

I have an script, and I thought i was working properly, but while checking manually some files, I realized tht the counting increases, specially for the ones that have a bak. 90% of the files without .bak have the correct number after counting, the other 10% seems because there are too big (or I dont know)... I would like to know what I did wrong? this is my code in summary:

```
import os, os.path
import fileinput
from glob import glob

seq = 0

wa = 0
wb = 0
wc = 0



out = open('../check/prev/stats.txt', 'w')
fnames = glob('../check/prev/RF*.st')
for i in range(len(fnames)):

    inFile = open(fnames[i])

    #print type(fnames[0])
    print seq
#   print len(fnames)
    for line in inFile:

        if line[0:6] == ("SinSon"):
            wa += 1
        if line[0:6] == ("SanSin"):
            wb += 1
        if line[0:6] == ("BlaBla"):
            wc += 1
        out.write(fnames[seq]+"\t"+str(wa)+"\t"+str(wb)+"\t"+str(wc)+"\n")

    seq += 1
    wa = 0
    wb = 0
    wc = 0
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Here is my advice: pick one file for which the result is wrong, and figure out what's going on (a good strategy would be to keep simplifying things until you can no longer reproduce the problem, and then take one step back).

Comment: I already tried with a small file. While countin the number of files that the script is processing only counts the ones that do not have ".bak". But if the file has a backup then the number increases. At the end seems also counting all the modifications saved on the backup. If I saved the file 10 times it counts them 10 times. Is there a way to restrict this?

Comment: Are your files increasing in their size then? Maybe your editor is copy-pasting lines and appending new data to those files?